# Which is the most important factor while drawing UML diagrams

Tags: uml

This is the interview question asked.

Which is the most important factor while drawing UML diagrams.

Comment: While drawing? A steady hand. :-)

Comment: Thats true :D but what should be in mind?

Comment: Like any language; correct syntax and semantics, i.e. it has to be valid UML, and it has to mean what you intended it to mean.  The question has no correct answer, its purpose is to see how you think (and whether you do think).  What did you say?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Understanding the requirements possibly.

or

Using a common set of rules/objects so that others understand what you're designing.

It's designed to get you speaking about UML, so they can gauge if you've used it before.
They're not looking for one particular answer.

Comment: +1 for insight into the "why"